# long-polling with more than 200,000 client

Tags: javascript, php, apache, nginx

I have more than 200,000 Customer and I would like to use long-polling to update orders status.

Apache configured to accept just 256 connection at the sametime,

Reference: [Apache Configure](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients)

is it possible to edit this setting to like 200,000?

any suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible? Test it, make a backup. But i do not advice accepting 200000 connections at the same time

Comment: Why would you have a static connection per customer? Would asynchronous long polling using 256 for 200,000 customers not be plenty?

Comment: Do you want me to test that with my 200,000 customer?

Comment: @Fran as i mentioned i would like to keep them up-to-date with orders status change.

Comment: @JackSmith but you don't need 200k concurrent connections for that.

Comment: @Fran what do you mean? lets say that i have just five customers and each customer is browsing the website and have 2 orders, Now i have changed a order status on database for customer number four. how he gets informed that a change occurs without long-polling and live connection?

Comment: What we do (website with about 60K business clients logged in concurrently) is we have an asynchronous process on the backend that changes the status of the orders in the database.  When the user performs his next action (reload a page anywhere in the site) we check the status of pending orders and display a small icon to warn him the status changed.  This way the check is triggered by the user and avoids keeping auto-updates or long-polling.  Another thing you could do is fake it by setting up an auto-refresh header every X minutes (make it long!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this on a private server or a server you can re-program?

I don't know from your question if it's a requirement to keep using Apache, but if possible I think Nginx would work much better for you here.

Nginx does not have the 256 connection limit that Apache does due to an [asynchronous, approach to handling connections.](https://www.nginx.com/blog/inside-nginx-how-we-designed-for-performance-scale/?_ga=2.49756654.913613657.1509017177-1860625347.1509017177)

Not sure what requirements your server has, but a basic nginx swap from apache is pretty simple and can be done following step by step tutorials online like this one:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-from-an-apache-web-server-to-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-vps

For long polling you can install a nginx module to make it an http push server like this one:

https://github.com/rsms/nginx_http_push_module

Anyhow maybe that's too much work and there's a more simple way to solve the problem, but I think that would be your best long term solution considering nginx is built from the ground up to handle these types of things.